# micronaut native ON windows 11 GIVES java.lang.ClassNotFoundException warnings

Tags: java, windows, micronaut, graalvm-native-image

With the environment below

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621

java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 20.0.2+9.1 (build 20.0.2+9-jvmci-23.0-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 20.0.2+9.1 (build 20.0.2+9-jvmci-23.0-b14, mixed mode, sharing)

Micronaut Version: 4.0.5
```

With a simple example project created with micronaut as below [github](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.spi.cloud/blob/main/runTut.txt)

```
mn create-app com.tugalsan.spi.cloud --build=maven --lang=java --features=graalvm,serialization-jackson
mn create-controller HelloController
mvnw package -Dpackaging=native-image
```

I am facing with so many java.lang.ClassNotFoundException s. And I did not even edit the sample code yet. Is it normal that micronaut behaves like that? [github](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.spi.cloud/blob/main/runOut.txt)

```
Warning: Could not resolve class com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdCompressCtx for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdCompressCtx.
...
Warning: Could not resolve class io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslClientSessionCache for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/internal/tcnative/SSLSessionCache.
...
Warning: Could not resolve class org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.
...
Warning: Could not resolve class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.
...
Warning: Could not resolve class org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.X509$Mappings for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.X509$Mappings.
...
```